# Ionic 3!! um slide + dois botões em baixo lado a lado

Tags: html, css, ionic, ionic3

Quero criar um slide com dois botões abaixo. Porém eu consegui por os dois botões na parte inferior lado a lado, mas o slide não funciona quando tento passar para o slide 2, 3.

```
<ion-slides id="slide">

  <ion-slide style="background-color: white">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: white">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: white">
    <h2>Slide 3</h2>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>

<ion-content >

  <button id="Entrar">Entrar</button>
  <button id="registrar">Registar</button>


</ion-content>
```

Codigo css

```
#Entrar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 620px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 188px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 89, 255);


}
#registrar{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 620px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 187px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 89, 255);
  font-size: 25px;




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde. Pelo que entendi você quer ter um slide e abaixo desse slide você quer acrescentar 2 botões.

Eu fiz utilizando os componentes que vêm junto com o ionic 3, caso você ja tenha usado o bootstrap 3 é mais fácil o entendimento.

Apaguei as classes que  tinha e criei apenas umas classe `.estilo-slide` para determinar uma altura para o slide, você pode alterar ou retirar se quiser, depende do seu uso. Já no HTML eu simplesmente acrescentei algumas classes que são nativas do Ionic para tornar o desenvolvimento mais ágil.

Criei a `div` antes dos botões para poder colocar a classe nativa `text-xs-center` que centraliza os elementos dentro da div, nesse caso os seus botões.

Já nos botões eu utilizei `class="pt-xs--4" ion-button color="primary"` que significam respectivamente, padding-top de 20px/4, `ion-button` chamada de botão do ionic e por fim a cor do botão.

Tudo o que eu disse aqui tem na [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/) do Ionic 3.

O código final ficou assim:

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slides class="estilo-slide">

      <ion-slide style="background-color: white">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
      </ion-slide>

      <ion-slide style="background-color: white">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      </ion-slide>

      <ion-slide style="background-color: white">
        <h2>Slide 3</h2>
      </ion-slide>

    </ion-slides>

    <div class="text-xs-center">
      <button class="pt-xs--4" ion-button color="primary">Entrar</button>
      <button class="pt-xs--4" ion-button color="secondary">Registar</button>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
.estilo-slide{
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: O seu exemplo deu certo. porem o botão não fica alinhando no slide. poderia me ajudar como fazer isso?

Comment: @W.Israel Você gostaria que os botões fiquem dentro do slide?

Comment: Isso mesmo, por exemplo, tem uma imagem no centro, com uns titulos, e os butões abaixo dele

Comment: como você fez para usar o bootstrap com ionic?